# Lifting idempotents modulo $J(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, idempotents

Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that $R/J(R)$ is von Neumann regular, where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$. I conjecture that the idempotents of $R/J(R)$ lift modulo $J(R)$. Is it a fact?

Indeed, this is equivalent to the statement that every direct summand of the $R$-module $R/J(R)$ would have a projective cover by Proposition 27.4 of "Rings and Categories of Modules" by Fuller & Anderson. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this conjecture is not true.

You can semi localize $\mathbb Z$ at two maximal primes, so that the ring mod the radical is a product of two fields.

But the localization is a domain, so obviously there aren't enough idempotents to lift to.

These are studied under the name [semiregular rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/88/), by the way. It's well covered in *Rings Related to Stable Range Conditions* by Chen, and in several works of Tuganbaev, I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation! What do you mean by "... semi localize $\mathbb Z$ at two maximal primes"? Principally, what does mean "to semi localize"?

Comment: @karparvar I think is pretty clear from the answer what this means: localize a ring $R$ at $R\setminus(p_1\cup p_2)$ for two prime ideals $p_1,p_2$.

Comment: @karparvar yes, user26857 is describing what I mean.  It appears in [this query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/commsearch/commresults/?has=28&lacks=51) in the DaRT